# Retrieve information from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently new in SQL language and I am struggling to understand how to retrieve correct information from tables below:

staff table

```
+------+----------+---------+-----------------+------+------+
| s_id | initials | s_name  | pos             | qual | d_id |
+------+----------+---------+-----------------+------+------+
| AA   | A.       | Tom     | Lecturer        | PhD  | RELI |
| BBB  | J.J.     | Jason   | Senior Lecturer | PhD  | RELI |
| CCC  | B.A.     | Andy    | Senior Lecturer | PhD  | BIOL |
| DD   | M.       | Mark    | Professor       | PhD  | BIOL |
| EE   | W.       | Alen    | Professor       | BA   | BIOL |
+------+----------+---------+-----------------+------+------+
```

research table

```
+------+-------+------------+-----------+
| s_id | r_id  | str_date   | fin_date  |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+
| BBB  | RESH1 |       1990 |      1998 |
| BBB  | RESH2 |       1980 |      1985 |
| DD   | RESH4 |       1995 |      1999 |
| AA   | RESH4 |       1992 |      1999 |
| CCC  | RESH8 |       1989 |      1994 |
| EE   | RESH5 |       1988 |      1989 |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to create a new table that will contains, staff s_name and how many different researches has each person did.

What I have until now is

```
select distinct s.s_name, count(r.s_id) 
from staff s 
inner join research r 
on s.s_id = r.s_id 
where s.s_id = r.s_id;
```

My result is,

```
+---------+---------------+
| s_name  | count(r.s_id) |
+---------+---------------+
| Jason   |             6 |
+---------+---------------+
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do :

```
select s.s_name, count(*) 
from staff s 
inner join research r 
on s.s_id = r.s_id 
group by r.s_id
```

Comment: This query will not work for the above example.Since you are grouping by r.s_id for staff name 'Jason' ccount of r_id will be 1

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks Sashi Kant for fast reply. Didn't know about grub by statement. For now on, I will have it in mind. Could you please explain to me, why we have asterisk in count()? Didn't get that point. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @AnandPhadke: Please check my query first, the grouping is done on s_id, which will return count=2 for 'jason'

Comment: ohh ok I got it.Bt now its nt allowing me to remove my down vote as you have to edit the answer.

Comment: @AnandPhadke: No issues yaar...:-)

Comment: @SashiKant you can edit your answer because you forgot a semicolon at the end I think. Then arandPhadke will be able to re-vote. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the datatype of S_ID between Staff table and research table. There might be white spaces in any one of the table. Otherwise use the `Trim` function in your join conditions, so that may receive the right result set.

Your query returns only the distinct id in the Staff table. You should use the `group by` in your SQL Statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Had no idea about group by clause! Now I am aware of it! Very useful, thanks @Gowdhaman008